# Searching across sub-arrays in Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

My title isn't very accurate, but I can't name the problem I'm having.

So I'm learning how to use firebase and angularfire, and I'm learning how to manipulate data.

Everything was find until I met this type of array.

[image]

This is my real time database from Firebase, and it's an history.

The main array is the history it selfs, it is composed in two array (0 and 1), which refers to the history of user 0 and user 1.

In array of user 0, there is his user ID (_ID), and two sub-arrays (0 and 1), which refers to the levels he did.

Each sub-arrays has the number of times the level has been done, the ID (_id) of the level, and few sub-sub-arrays that contains data of each time the level has been run.

Kinda complicated ! I hope you understand my database. I agree that I don't have the best practice about how to structure my database.

My problem is, I'm looking to serach across this type of arrays for my angularjs app.

For example, I'm trying to make these vars:

```
$scope.history
$scope.userHistory
$scope.currentLevelUserHistory
$scope.lastRunCurrentLevelUserHistory
```

I managed to get the two first vars, but I don't understand why I doesn't work how the nexts.

Getting history is very easy, I'm just using this function in my factory

```
getHistoriques : function () {
    return historiques;
}
```

Where "historiques" refers to this

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("historiques");
var historiques = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

Getting userHistory was a bit more tricky.

I created this function

```
function search(key, array){
    console.log("Searching array with the key : " + key);
    for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i]._id === key) {

            console.log(array[i]);
            return array[i];

        }
        else {

        }
    }
}
```

And the output is an object like that.

[image]

But to get to the next step : currentLevelUserHistory. This was impossible for me. I tried 10 differents way, but I couldn't get it working.

My last attempt, was for me to re-inject the output of the previous object, with the level ID, in the search function.

But I'm getting "undefined".

I tried so many things, like adding some [0] to my object, adding bunch of stuffs. But i can't figure out why it doesn't work. For me the array and the sub array is always the same.

Why is it not working ? It's because of the output of the function is modifying my array ?

I know my question is very long. So many thanks to anyone who had the courage to read it.

Thank you a lot.

First EDIT :

```
users
    |
    - userId (according to firebase auth)
        |
        - name : ...
        |
        - surname : ...
        |
        - age : ...
        |
        - allowed levels :
                        |
                        - allowedLevel001 : levelId
                        |
                        - allowedLevel002 : levelId
                        |
                        - allowedLevel003 : levelId
        -...

levelsData
    |
    - levelId
        |
        - level name : ...
        |
        - level description : ...
        |
        - first step
            |
            - step name : ...
            |
            - step desc : ...
            |
            - action needed : ...
            |
            - time : ...
        - second step
            |
            - step name : ...
            |
            - step desc : ...
            |
            - action needed : ...
            |
            - time : ...    
    |
        -...    

levelsRunData
    |
    - userId+levelId
        |
        - run001
            |
            -
            first step result :
                |
                - ...
            second step result :
                |
                - ...   
            |
            -...
        - run002
            |
            -
            first step result :
                |
                - ...
            second step result :
                |
                - ...   
            |
            -...
```

Comment: Not that I am answering your question but just be aware that when you read on 'historiques' you are reading your whole database. You have everything already in that dataset so you could populate the  other variables you are looking for by processing just that dataset. However, that dataset could be potentially huge and very expensive, on time and money, to download.

Comment: I'm learning, so I still don't know about optimization and security. I understand that downloading the whole history isn't optimized and secure because the user have access to other user's history (so it's huge), but for me this project is a lesson. I will not use any of this unless it's completely done, optimized and secure.

What do you suggest to retrieve only the wanted data ? Thank you

Comment: What do you intend these variables to hold ie. are they for a single, specified user or all users?


$scope.userHistory
$scope.currentLevelUserHistory
$scope.lastRunCurrentLevelUserHistory

Comment: Well, the user is logging, he launch the level script, and the script find out in the whole database where his data is located and apply it to these variables. But only him can see them. but every user can create these variables each times they want to do a level. I don't know if i'm very clear. sorry ^^

Answer (score 2):

I would like to make some suggestions regarding your database structure. They are based on what I think is your use case. I may be completely wrong of course. First though, a couple of comments:

1. You need to think of the Firebase RTDB database as a map of key/value pairs, not an array. It does allow you to post an array to the db but it will create a series of key/value pairs from it with keys starting at 0 and incrementing by 1 (you are sort-of doing this in your current structure but I think it can lead to other problems).
2. You need to think what the database should look like when you need to handle 100k users. The storage and data download volumes then become very important or you app will grind to a halt and Google will present you with a bill in the $1000s.

IMHO your users need to be identified by a decent unique key, not 0, 1, 2. This will bite you back in the long term, trust me. Many db structures make use of the userid that is created when a user is authenticated to the app via Firebase authentication - you should look at using that for all references to your users in the database. That gets rid of the id: property that you are storing against each user cos it's already in the key.

I can't see what data you have under sub-sub-arrays 0 and 1 but you are already down 5 levels and, whilst it's doable, it is not good to go deep nesting in a NoSQL db.

So, again IMHO, your database could look like the following (I'm assuming historiques is root and you don't need to keep any other details about a user eg. name, age, etc. If you do then you need a node called users with the userId as key.):

Two database nodes called levelsCompleted and levelRunData. They would look like...

```
levelsCompleted
    |
    - userId
        |
        - levelId001 : levelRunCount
        (number of zeroes in levelId depends on how many possible levels there are)
        |
        - levelId002 : levelRunCount
        |
        -...

levelsRunData
    |
    - userId+levelIdnnn (concatenate the two ids)
        |
        - run001
            |
            - run data (don't know what is in here).
        (number of zeroes in run depends on how many possible runs there are)
        |
        - run002
            |
            - run data
        |
        - run003
            |
            - run data
        |
        -...
```

It then becomes fairly simple to read the data you need based on the user's id and the level id.
Hope this makes sense.

**Update Based on Your First Edit:**

Please see suggested structure below. I am now using actual (suggested) property names. Also, for clarity, here are the suggested record keys for each node:

```
Node            Key Format                                   Name in Structure
----            ---------------------                        -----------------
users           <28 character user id from firebase_auth>    userId
levelsData      <'level'nnn eg. level001, level002>          levelId
levelsRunData   <userId + levelId + 'run'nnn>                N/a
```

We can then discuss it in the chat room.

Database Structure:

```
users
    |
    - userId (according to firebase auth)
        |
        - name : ...
        |
        - surname : ...
        |
        - age : ...
        |
        - allwdLvls
            |
            - level001 : levelRunCount
            |
            - level002 : levelRunCount
            |
            - level003 : levelRunCount
        -...

levelsData
    |
    - level001
        |
        - levelName : ...
        |
        - levelDesc : ...
        |
        - step001
            |
            - stepName : ...
            |
            - stepDesc : ...
            |
            - actionNeeded : ...
            |
            - time : ...
        - step002
            |
            - stepName : ...
            |
            - stepDesc : ...
            |
            - actionNeeded : ...
            |
            - time : ...    
    |
    - level002
        |
        - levelName : ...
        -... 
    -...

levelsRunData
    |
    - <userId>+<levelId>+run001
        |
        - step001
            |
            - ...
            |
            - ...
        |
        - step002
            |
            - ...
            |
            - ...
        |
        -...
    - <userId>+<levelId>+run002
        |
        - step001
            |
            - ...
            |
            - ...
        |
        - step002
            |
            - ...
            |
            - ...
        |
        -...
    |
    -...
```

Comment: thank you a lot for your message. I understand more things now. I'm very grateful. I tried to arrange my database according to your recommandation, I don't know how to do a long reply so I edited my question and added the quote on the bottom.

I have few more questions about searching and about concatenated ids, but if you can give me your opinion on the new structure of my db it will be nice. :)

Comment: Responded via SO chat in this room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/210871/room-for-grahamd-and-maxdev99

Comment: I have send a new message. I don't know if you are receiving notifications on the chat so I'm telling it here. Thank you.

Comment: Responded on chat.